# how to isolate a user class from other users? TELEBOT

Tags: python, api

I make a telegram bot to search for anime. For API requests, I made an additional file with a class containing class fields as search parameters as well as functions that return dictionaries with data. In the main file, I created an object of this class so that the user fills in the class fields as he enters information, and then gets the result from the class method. Everything works well for one user, but when using the bot by different users at the same time, choosing one makes changes for all users. how can a class be isolated so that everyone works with a personal instance

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import n
import psy_db

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
search_class=n.ani_search()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=f'hello,{message.from_user.first_name}!')
```

```
import requests
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class ani_search:
    id_user:Optional[int]=None
    name_media: Optional[str] = None
    name_char: Optional[str] = None
    rank: Optional[int] = None
    type: Optional[str] = None
    genre: Optional[list] = None
    id_char: Optional[int] = None
    id_media: Optional[int] = None
    page: Optional[int]= 1
    page_char: Optional[int]= 1
    search_type: Optional[str]= None
    iter = 0
```

I tried to dynamically create class objects for each user by his ID using the vars() function, but it didn't work.
I haven't been studying python for very long, so don't laugh :)

Comment: Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem with multiple instances.

Comment: @Barmar:for example, in my class there is a "page" field that acts as a counter. it is designed to scroll the results back and forth. I put this variable in the "print" function to fix its change when called from the user.When using the bot by two people at the same time, when the first one scrolls the page forward, then the counter of the second one also increases by one.
I think it's not quite correct to create an object in this way:search_class=n.ani_search(), but I can't imagine how to do it differently

Comment: @Barmar: To be honest, I don't know how I could demonstrate this since the work is done on the server.thank you for your attention to my problem

Comment: Each time you call `n.ani_search()` it should create a new instance. Unless you use class attributes or share data structures between the instances, they should be isolated from each other. `@dataclass` should turn all those variables into instance attributes, so I can't see where you're having a problem.

Comment: @Barmar: however, unfortunately this "search_class" object is the same for all users. But I solved the problem by creating a dictionary, with the user ID as the keys and a dictionary with search parameters as the value. thus, all search parameters entered by the user are recorded not in the class but in the dictionary, and the result is output according to the user's ID. And I got rid of the class. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The point of using OOP is to create multiple objects.

Comment: @barmar: I understand it. But the problem is that the user does not create an object when using the bot. I have already created this object, and the user only uses it. But another user uses the same object as the others, changing it, and this change occurs in others. It's just that apparently this method doesn't quite fit my project.

Comment: The bot should create a separate object to represent each user.

Comment: @barmar however, he doesn't do it

Comment: I'm suggesting that you should redesign it so it DOES do this. The benefit of using OOP is that you package the data for each user into a separate object.